# Android application doesn't update because of background service

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services

I published new version of [my program](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xyz.timeio) in google play but Android application doesn't update on my devices because of permanently running background service. Applicatio update only after device rebooting, I need to update it in background. What to do?

Is ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED broadcast send before or after update?

Comment: background running service doesn't stop update .. are you sure it's background service not allowing app to upgrade? do you see any logs. If so share log details. refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242007/how-do-android-app-upgrades-work-technically/31149441#31149441

Comment: Thank you! I was wrong, application updated little ago